# how to match between two strings stdin using grep?

Tags: bash, grep, wc

I have 2 expressions I want to compare between them so I wrote:

```
result=(`echo "${strings[0]}" | grep -i -w "${strings[1]}" | wc -w`)
```

but when I echo result its empty... why?

the..

more code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function checkStrings {
   strings=$*
   result=(`echo "${strings[0]}" | grep -i -w "${strings[1]}" | wc -w`)
   echo $result ${strings[*]}
}

checkStrings "Avi" "Avi"
```

output: 
0 Avi Avi

answer from "Blue Moon"
change strings=$* into strings=($*)

it works thnx

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Allendar There's no reason keep the last sentence since the backticks are shown after the edit (which wasn't before edit and which is why he wrote it in the first place). It's not part of the question and I see no reason to have it.

Comment: example:
strings={ Avi Avi }
so wc should put 1 in result.. but it put 0

Comment: I'm just noting that because it happens so often that questions get cut in so heavily that it breaks the actual question. No matter if that's the case in this situation; even if it's redundant it wouldn't need removal and won't make the question less understandable. It's not meant as an offense :)

Comment: @user3036061 The way you assign the array is wrong. Otherwise, your code does what you expect. See here: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: You should not use curly braces when defining the array `strings`.. Use `strings=("Avi" "Avi")`

Comment: ok thnx alot I see it realy do so it sounds the problem is from somthing else I will search for it and put more code if I stuck
THNX alot!!

Comment: still not working
see edit

Comment: @user3036061 Your array assignment is wrong! Change it to: `strings=($*)` in the function. If you don't use brackets the whole of the parameters passed is assigned to just strings[0] and strings[1] is just empty. Hence, you get 0.

Answer (score 0):

The result is not empty:

```
$ strings=( Avi Avi )
$ r=(`echo "${strings[0]}" | grep -i -w "${strings[1]}" | wc -w`)
$ echo $r
1
```

Just to test that it works properly, lets do a case that should have a zero result:

```
$ strings=( Avi2 Avi )
$ r=(`echo "${strings[0]}" | grep -i -w "${strings[1]}" | wc -w`)
$ echo $r
0
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to define `result` as an array since `wc -w` return a single element (scalar).

Try

```
result=$(grep -i -w "${strings[1]}" <<< "${strings[0]}" | wc -w)
```

*** Update ***

Based on the updated question, you could try:

```
#! /bin/bash

function checkStrings {
   strings=($*)
   result=$(grep -i -w "${strings[1]}" <<< "${strings[0]}" | wc -w)
   echo $result ${strings[*]}
}

checkStrings "Avi" "Avi"
```

gives output:

```
1 Avi Avi
```